# Customer friendly bug and FR tracker

Tags: web-apps, web-development, issue-tracker

We have a small development team (5 developers) with many (20-30) small web projects. There are usually 2-5 person from the customer side who can submit errors, so we need to manage more than 100 users. To avoid any argument we would like to identify each customer account. I mean a simple guest account is not an option.

We try to manage customer bug reports and feature request. Our customer usually have no IT background.

We have used multiple solutions internally in the past years like: Jira, Mantis, Bugzilla, YouTrack, Backlog.
Major problem was, that most of them were too complex for non IT persons.

Backlog was the most promising but because of user requirements we need a package that costs $100/month. We would like a cheaper alternative up to 20-30USD/month

It can be cloud based or self hosted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Asana? YouTrack?

Comment: Unfortunately they are much more expensive in case of this user requirement.

Comment: Did you google for `alternative to backlog`?  There is some good info

Comment: I did. A lot of result are too expensive, or too developer focused. I didn't tried all of them.

Comment: I don't know of one, sorry. I do hope that you get an answer.  Mayer don't look for "bug tracker"? Maybe "incident reporter" or similar?